# Webservice access problem with multiuser access

Tags: sql-server, web-services, delphi-10.3-rio

I have created a web service calling SQL stored procedures. It is in fact a replacement for a previous SQL Endpoint, using the same SP's as the Endpoint did. The web service is called by a Win32 program, without HTTPRIO, using the service directly like this:

```
var Service : IApp3TWS;
    Terminal: TTerminal;
begin
  Service  := IApp3TWS1.GetIApp3TWS();
  Terminal := Service.WS_TerminalGet(trm);
  ..
  ..    
end;
```

IAPP3TWS is the pas file created by the WDSL importer.

I'm not passing any credentials like username or password. Still it functions flawlessly with a single user, but not with more users calling the same service at the same time.

The Webservice is created by the Delphi Webservice wizard, and wrapped in a TService shell, also created using the Delphi wizard, and finally installed on a server (the SQL server in fact) as a service (http.sys), and the username and -password used to allow the service to "log on as a service" is also allowed access to the SQL database and tables. And as I said, it all functioning correct, when only one Win32 program call at a time.

When I try to call the same service with 2 or more win32 programs, on different machines, one usually gets through, whereas the other (or others) gets various errors like;

> Access Violation. One also got a ADOStoredProc.Parameter not found...

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Today I changed the Win32 program to use HTTPRIO when calling the services, and tests now shows errors like "ADOStorecProc" Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset. But I always set ADO procedure name, parameters, prepare and call either opn og execsql depending on the operation. Clould it be a question of property sessings on the ADO component..

Comment: Btw: thanks to Dale K and esat for the help editing my question to appear nice and precise.

Comment: Can anyone tell me where the safe area is in a webservice ? In a recent IntraWeb appliction I've created, the safe area inside the session, is between Form = class and the END of that def. Putting all the vars insid, made them safe from other sessions. How it that in a web service ? Would that be likewise between the class def and the corresponding end ?

Comment: The problem appears to be solved, and it was, as my main concern has evolved around, the web service which was the culprit. Looking for a similar problem as in a recent IW application I made (see my previous comment), I am creating the web service with a call "dm := TApp3TDB.create(nil);" in the procedure for each web service call, just before setting dm.adostoredproc.procedurename and other ADO related stuff. "dm" is the datamodule where my ADO components are placed. Solution appears to be to move the definition dm : TApp3TDB; into the private area of the web service class. Continues...

Comment: Continued...Tests no longer fail with errors, And that correspond to the solution for the previous problem of my IW application, which also was solved by including all vars inside the class and end markers..